# Can logic and mathematics be used together?

Tags: logic, notation

I have been wondering if logical symbols ($\to$, $\sim$, etc.) can be used with traditional mathematical notation ($+$, $/$, etc.) in the same equation.

For example, would the following equation be valid?

$$\sum_{i=0}^n n + i \to i \geq 100 \therefore n_f = 100$$

Comment: ???? A number (the sum) implies a proposition (the inequality)? Syntax error!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really take time to come up with a legitimate equation, I just was wondering if the symbols could be used in the same equation.

Comment: That's not an equation.

Comment: Of course! For example $$(x^2 = 4) \to \Big((x = 2) \lor (x + 2 = 0)\Big).$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews My apologies, expression

Comment: it all depends, the big question is what does it all mean and how do you use it

Comment: The usual symbols of logic are part of standard mathematical notation.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem, provided you will stay with syntactic rules, i.e. rules of formation for terms and formulas.

In particular, you can write mathematical formulas in formal arithmetics, that is first-order logic (with equality) plus the $0$ individual constant, the $S$ successor function (unary), and the $+$ and $\times$ binary functions ("sum" and "product", respectively).

You can write formulas like :

> $x=0$
>
> $\lnot (0=1)$
>
> $\forall x (\lnot 0 = S(x))$.

The advise to respect the formation rules means, as said in the above comments, that you must use propositional *connectives* (like $\lor$ and $\land$) between formulas; so you can write :

> $x = 0 \lor x = 1$

but you **cannot**, e.g. write something like : $0 \land x = 1$, because $0$ is a *term* and not a *formula*.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Logical symbols are used to connect propositions. In mathematics, propositions usually involve symbolic shorthand. So it's perfectly reasonable to use logical symbols to connect mathematical propositions.

For example, to communicate that a function $f$ is discontinuous at $0$, one might write

> $$\bigg( (\lim_{t\to 0^+}f(t) = 0)\wedge (\lim_{t\to 0^-}f(t) = 1)\bigg)\Rightarrow \lnot \bigg( \forall \varepsilon>0\ \exists\delta>0:|t|<\delta\Rightarrow |f(t)-f(0)|<\varepsilon\bigg)$$

A note of caution: Overreliance on logical symbols can obscure communication. In my experience, it takes more time to parse symbols than to read natural language.

I find the only time I use logical symbols is when I'm trying to wrap my head around a particularly delicate point of logic. The discipline of writing out the symbols is an effective learning tool. However, in informal communication between mathematicians (e.g. a seminar talk), the only symbols I've seen commonly used are $\forall$, $\exists$, and $\Rightarrow$/$\Leftarrow$. Anything more would cause the audience to spend more time trying to read the board and less time trying to understand the math.